# C# Export Table to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

How can I export this data table to excel using: "**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**" I have this code witch grabs all the data form Master table and want to export it to excel for better view, don't want to use datagrid. There are a lot of post regarding this topic I think, but usually just recommend using some ad on like "closedxml"

```
        OleDbConnection mycon;           
        DataTable Table = new DataTable("AllData");

        mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jm11321\Documents\DB.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");

        string command = "Select *From Master";
        OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(command,mycon);

        OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleDbCmd);
        mycon.Open();
        adapt.Fill(Table);
        mycon.Close();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll library from [here](http://files.cnblogs.com/fan0136/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.rar). Add new class file in your project say ExcelUtility. Just write down the following code in it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelDemo
{
    public class ExcelUtility
    {
        public static void CreateExcel(DataSet ds, string excelPath)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            try
            {
                //Previous code was referring to the wrong class, throwing an exception
                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    }
                }

                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(excelPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();

                releaseObject(xlApp);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private static void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch
            {
                obj = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Now in main code just pass the dataset object and excel path as below.

```
ExcelUtility.CreateExcel(ds, "D:\\Demo.xls");
```

I have already tested and using this in my projects.

Comment: I get an error in "Excel.Application xlApp;" error "Error 2 Interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead." @Dinesh Maind

Comment: Edit-1 "Excel._Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();" this fixed that problem, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: This code doesn't add Datatable column names to the exported Excel though

Answer (score 3):

I know that there is already an answer, although here is another approach

```
 var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
        worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
        workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```

whats also really amazing about this approach is that you can put your dataset table or table into the workbook like such

```
 var wb = new XLWorkbook();

        var dataTable = GetTable("Information");

        // Add a DataTable as a worksheet
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);

        wb.SaveAs("AddingDataTableAsWorksheet.xlsx");
```

the dll is [here](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Just remember to add a table name to your dataset tables and datatables.